# If $R$ is commutative and $M$ is an $R$-module, does every element of $R$ determine an $R$-module endomorphism of $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, modules

> If $R$ is commutative and $M$ is an $R$-module, we have a ring homomorphism $\alpha: R \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(M)$. But is the image of $\alpha$ exactly $\mathrm{End}_{R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}}(M)$?

Since $\alpha_r(m)=r\cdot m$, we have $$\alpha_r(s\cdot m)=r\cdot(s\cdot m)=(rs)\cdot m=(sr)\cdot m=s\cdot (r\cdot m)=s\alpha_r(m).$$

> **So, $\alpha_r$ is in fact an $R$-module endomorphism?**

Comment: Suppose that $R$ is not integrally closed in some ring $S$, and choose $x \in S \setminus R$ that is integral over $R$.  Then $xM \subseteq M$ for some f.g. faithful $R[x]$-module $M$.  Thus $x$ defines an endomorphism on $M$ which is not multiplication by an element of $R$.  So the image of $\alpha$ is generally not all of the endormorphisms of $M$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan That's an answer (and it will be a full answer if you just confirm that $\alpha_r$ is indeed an $R$-module endomorphsm). Why are you posting it in the comment section?

Comment: @Arthur it's not clear to me what the question is really asking.  The emphasis doesn't seem to be on whether $\alpha$ surjects onto the module endomorphisms of $M$ - although it does ask that - but rather on the matter of whether $\alpha(r)$ is an endomorphism of $M$ as an $R$-module more than just an abelian group.  The answer to the latter was clearly yes, as Al Jebr demonstrated in the post.  As to the former, the answer is no, which is why I commented, but I'm not sure if Al Jebr actually intented to ask that.